# Fast way to work in a group on an Angular gh-pages project?

Tags: angular, github-pages

So i want to work on a project of mine, which is made of an angular website. I host it on gh-pages, it works and all **BUT** i have an issue with the slowness of having to build **EVERYTIME** I want to modify something.

Do you have any idea on how to dodge that ? or do it automatically ? speed it up maybe ?

Commands I use are

`ng build --configuration=production --base-href https://roirtur.github.io/NDI2023/`

and then

`ngh --dir dist/browser`

this thing take a while and then github has to make other checks that also take a while.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: IDK Angular, but it seems [incremental compilation](https://nx.dev/recipes/angular/setup-incremental-builds-angular) is possible (on higher versions). Have you tried this, or is it not compatible?

Comment: @l3l_aze I did not try no, i'll let you know when I have time to try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @l3l_aze Well, it seems to hard to put it in place. Thanks for the recommendation but i might just work in local for a while and upload at the very end, it should work (and it's more a dev/prod environment too so it's good)